# Blogname and Blogdescription in Pagelines DMS Options Panel

Tags: theme-options, options, bloginfo

I am attempting up set up a front end options panel in the pagelines-dms framework, from which users will be able to change the blogname and blogdescription. So far I have set up the form which has the text fields 'blogname' & 'blogdescription' as below

```
add_filter('pl_sorted_settings_array', 'add_global_panel2');
function add_global_panel2($settings){
    $settings['privacy'] = array(
        'name' => 'Blog Name',
        'icon' => 'icon-eye-open',
        'opts' => array(
            // Regular Options Engine
            array(
            'key' => 'blogname',
        'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'blog Name'
        ),
            // Regular Options Engine
            array(
                'id'   => 'blogdescription',
        'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'blog description'

            ),
        )
    );
    // Finally we return the new array
    return $settings;
}
```

However, I'm unsure of how to link this up with the wordpress options. I have found the following functions in the pagelines-dms editor.settings.php which I beleive holds the key to my success but I'm unsure how to implement it in the right way:

```
/*
 * This class contains all methods for interacting with WordPress' data system
 * It has no dependancy so it can be used as a substitute for WordPress native functions
 * The options system inherits from it.
 */
class PageLinesData {

    function meta($id, $key, $default = false){

        $val = get_post_meta($id, $key, true);

        if( (!$val || $val == '') && $default ){

            $val = $default;

        } elseif( is_array($val) && is_array($default)) {

            $val = wp_parse_args( $val, $default );

        }

        return $val;

    }

    function meta_update($id, $key, $value){

        update_post_meta($id, $key, $value);

    }


    function opt( $key, $default = false, $parse = false ){

        $val = get_option($key);

        if( !$val ){

            $val = $default;

        } elseif( $parse && is_array($val) && is_array($default)) {

            $val = wp_parse_args( $val, $default );

        }

        return $val;

    }

    function opt_update( $key, $value ){

        update_option($key, $value);

    }

    function user( $user_id, $key, $default = false ){

        $val = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);

        if( !$val ){

            $val = $default;

        } elseif( is_array($val) && is_array($default)) {

            $val = wp_parse_args( $val, $default );

        }

        return $val;

    }

    function user_update( $user_id, $key, $value ){
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $value );
    }



}
```

(a copy of the entire file can be found here: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/dms/1.0.2/editor/editor.settings.php)

If anyone could help I would be more than grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

So I have found a solution to my problem;

Pagelines encodes each key and value pair into a json string, within in its own option called pl_settings in the wp_options table.

They also give you access to each of these key->value pairs using the following: $value = pl_setting('option_key')

Thus I have taken the approach of using the following code to fulfil my needs:

```
add_filter('pl_sorted_settings_array', 'add_global_panel2');
function add_global_panel2($settings){
    $settings['privacy'] = array(
        'name' => 'About Your Loved One',
        'icon' => 'icon-heart',
        'opts' => array(
            // Regular Options Engine
        array(
                'key' => 'blogname',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'the name of your loved one',
                'help' => 'test'
        ),
            // Regular Options Engine
            array(
                'key'   => 'blogdescription',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'a message to your loved one',
                'help' => 'test'
            ),
        )
    );
    update_option('blogname', $value = pl_setting('blogname'));
    update_option('blogdescription', $value = pl_setting('blogdescription'));
    // Finally we return the new array
    return $settings;
}
```

The only downside of working it in this way is that I need to refresh the browser twice once updating either of the values for it to actually take effect on it's corresponding option.

If anyone could better this then please let me know.